# beq address in MIPS code

Tags: architecture, mips, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I can't understand what is the full address of `next` after line 9.
I tried to calculate it but I got different addresses by Add the last 16 bits of the next label to the pc+4 and add it to the current row address.

The Exactely question is:

> Based on the command in row 9 and the rest of the columns in this row,
>   what is the full address of the label next?

**MIPS code:**
[image]

**Answers:**

[image]

Comment: `next` is a label. It should be found somewhere in the assembly code marking a line `next:`.

Comment: Yes. but the question is to find the fully address by all parameters we have.

Comment: No. It's a past question from test.

Comment: Why is it unanswerable? The next label is 16 last bits no? Can't I Add them to the pc+4 and add it to the current row address?

Comment: Ah, I see where the problem is. No, you cannot just add the 16 bits to the pc + 4. You need to multiply the value by 4 (= number of bytes per instruction) and sign-extend the value to 32 bit, *then* add to pc + 4. Put another way, the offset is a signed number of instructions, counted from the instruction after the branch.

Comment: Can you explain with spesific examples? What do you mean multiple the value? the 0xFFFB?

Comment: In addition, Isn't it legitimate question? Why did you down-vote my question?

Comment: `0xfffb` interpreted as a signed 16-bit number is `-5` in decimal. Multiply `-5 * 4 = -20`. Convert `-20` to signed 32-bit number: `0xffffffec`. Add `0xffffffec + 0x400010 + 0x4`.

Comment: In other words, count `-5` instructions from the `nor` following the `beq`, look at the address.

Comment: Great explanation. Would you like to add it as answer?

Comment: No. I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate, I'm just too lazy to search right now.